# Scanner throws NoSuchElementException when used with space-containing Pattern

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read a specified file format from input with a `Scanner` and a `Pattern`, like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\sx\\s\\d+");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = "";
try {
    input = sc.next(p);
} catch(NoSuchElementException ne) {
    System.out.println("No such token");
}
sc.close();
System.out.println(input);
```

But when I use `1 x 1` as input, it throws the `NoSuchElementException`
With the pattern being `\\d+x\\d+` and input `1x1` it works, but not with spaces in the pattern, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Post the exception here.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran I meant it throws the NoSuchElementException, the one I catch. Maybe I should mention that in the question

Comment: @Big_Chair actually it throws `InputMismatchException` which extends `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Depends on the input, but I think your pattern will be more useful as `"\\d+\\s*x\\s*\\d+"` or `"\\d+\\s?x\\s?\\d+"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.

And it also says:

> public String next(Pattern pattern)
>
> Returns the next token if it matches the specified pattern.

So, your code reads chars until the next white space, and return them if they match your pattern. Which is not the case since your pattern matches strings containing a white space, and a token can't contain one.

Comment: But it says "by default", so when I change the pattern it should read whitespaces too, or not?

Comment: How about suggesting `sc.useDelimiter("\\n");` or similar

Comment: @Big_Chair: see Dukeling's comment. Calling the `next(Pattern)` method doesn't change the delimiter used by the scanner. It just returns the next token, obtained using the scanner delimiter, if the token matches the regexp.

Comment: @Dukeling it should be `sc.useDelimiter("\n");` instead.

Comment: @Dukeling It's both amazing and puzzling :)

Comment: @Big_Chair For me worked `"\\d+\\sx\\s\\d+"` pattern and `"\r\n"` delimeter. To make it more OS independent it should be probably `sc.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`